# Multiple YAxis with different tick size

Tags: charts, size, flot

Just want to find out if anyone have encountered this problem before.

Basically I am currently using Flot version 0.8. I am trying to plot a chart with multiple yaxis against datetime in xaxis.

The Left yaxis are for values which normally range between 10-80 whereas right yaxis are for values range between 100-500.

Is that even possible to have them plotted with the same tick size (E.g., 20) and the dimension of the chart is fixed.

At the moment, FLOT will automatically apply different tick size on left and right yaxis.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tickSize option to set the same interval on both axes.  See the [customizing the axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) section of the docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried setting that option, however because the height of the chart is not enough so it is not able to show all the points that have higher values. I guess the dimension of the chart have to change after all.